# Use reference to object instantiation from inside class' code

Tags: c++, oop, this

In Java you can write code inside a class named MyClass like

```
MyClass.this
```

and it will use the reference to the instantiated object while the code is running.  (So, the instantiated object "knows" its own address and can use a reference to itself using that keyword.)

So, basically, I think I could achieve this using C++ with a function like

```
MyClass::useSelf (MyClass* first, MyClass* second);
```

And, just always pass the reference to the instantiated object as the first argument.  Then, the class can get its reference from inside the class.

So,

```
MyClass* instantiated1 = new MyClass();
MyClass* instantiated2 = new MyClass();
instantiated1.useSelf (instantiated1, instantiated2);
```

And inside the class write the function:

```
MyClass::useSelf (MyClass* first, MyClass* second)
{
  second.someFunction (first);  // hypothetical function
}
```

So, I pass the object's own instantiation reference.
But I would like to be able to skip the first argument and just use

```
MyClass* instantiated1 = new MyClass();
MyClass* instantiated2 = new MyClass();
instantiated1.useSelf (instantiated2);
```

Now inside the class I need to have somewhere in that function

```
MyClass::useSelf (MyClass* second)
{
  // EDIT: Code that works!
  second->someFunction(this);
}
```

I don't think the above code can be made to work, but the idea is that now I can get the reference to the object's instantiation from inside the class on its own rather than have to hand it the reference to itself from the outside code.

If you're wondering why the heck I want to do this, I am using a virtual function to take advantage of inheritance.  And, the derived class might need to use the base class' function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this` pointer is an implicit parameter to all nonstatic member functions. Therefore, inside a member function, `this` may be used to refer to the invoking object, as it is a constant pointer that holds the memory address of the current object.

Comment: Thanks!  I think I was running into trouble because I forgot the scope operator :: so the function I was working with wasn't considered a member function, so it wouldn't let me use the keyword this.

Answer (score 1):

`this` isn't hypothetical, it's a keyword in C++:

```
void MyClass::useSelf (MyClass* second)
{
    // Code that works
    second->someFunction(this);
}
```